# Question regarding convergence is Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, normed-spaces

I have been reading Evan's book for PDE, and i have a question about the following definition

**Definition**. **(i)** Let $\{u_m\}_{m=1}^\infty, u \in W^{k,p}(U)$. We say $u_m$ converges to u in $W^{k,p}(U)$, written
\begin{equation}
u_m \to u \quad \text{in} \quad W^{k,p}(U),
\end{equation} 
provided
\begin{equation}
\lim_{m \to \infty} ||u_m - u||_W^{k,p}(U) = 0.
\end{equation}
**(ii)** We write
\begin{equation}
u_m \to u \quad \text{in} \quad W_{loc}^{k,p}(U),
\end{equation} 
to mean
\begin{equation}
u_m \to u \quad \text{in} \quad W^{k,p}(V),
\end{equation} 
for each $V \subset \subset U$.

So what is the defintion trying to say
**1.** If we have convergence in $W_{loc}^{k,p}(U)$ will we have convergence on $W^{k,p}(U)$, or can we have a subset that is not necessary compact where convergence cannot happen.?

**2.** If we have **(i)** we will have **(ii)**?

So, can u help me with those two questions, and if u want to give me some extra info about something that u guys think that i should know concerning this definition please do it.

Thank yoy in advance

Answer (score 3):

(i) implies (ii) since if $V\subset U$ then $\int_V|D^k u_m-Du|^p dx\le \int_U|D^k u_m-Du|^p dx\to 0$. 
On the other hand (ii) does not imply (i). Take $u_m=\frac1m$. Then on every open bounded set $V$ you will have $||u_m-0||_{W^{k,p}(V)}=\frac1m(\mathcal{L^1}(V))^{1/p}\to 0$ but $||u_m-0||_{W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R})}=\infty.$

Comment: when u have $||u_m-0||_{W^{k,p}(V)}=\frac1m(\mathcal{L^1}(V))^{1/p}$ what do u mean with $\mathcal{L^1}(V))^{1/p}$?

Comment: no, if you take $u_m$ to be a constant function $\frac1m$ then its $L^p(V)$ norm will be $\frac1m (\mathcal{L}^1(V))^{1/p}$ while the derivatives will have norm zero.

Answer (score 1):

If $V \subseteq U$ then $\| u|_{V} \|_{W^{k,p}(V)} \leq \| u \|_{W^{k,p}(U)}$ so if $u_n$ converges to $u$ in $W^{k,p}(U)$ then $u_n|_{V}$ will converge to $u|_{V}$ in $W^{k,p}(V)$. Hence, converges in $W^{k,p}(U)$ implies converges in $W^{k,p}_{\text{loc}}(U)$ but it does not work the other way because a sequence might converge on each open subset $V$ which is compactly contained in $U$ but might fail to converge on the whole of $U$.